# How to enable druid kafka ingestion?

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

I am following druid documentation but as I run the command

```
curl -XPOST -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d @quickstart/tutorial/wikipedia-kafka-supervisor.json http://localhost:8081/druid/indexer/v1/supervisor
```

I get the error

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file 
Warning: "quickstart/tutorial/wikipedia-kafka-supervisor.json", this 
makes an 
Warning: empty POST.
```

so where this file exists `wikipedia-kafka-supervisor.json`?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the content of this file on [Github](https://github.com/apache/incubator-druid/blob/master/examples/quickstart/tutorial/wikipedia-kafka-supervisor.json).

You'd need to first donwload Kafka:

```
curl -O https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/0.10.2.2/kafka_2.12-0.10.2.2.tgz
tar -xzf kafka_2.12-0.10.2.2.tgz
cd kafka_2.12-0.10.2.2
```

Then fire up a Kafka broker:

```
./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

and create a `wikipedia` topic to which the data will be sent:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic wikipedia
```

Finally, you can start the service to enable Druid Kafka ingestion:

```
curl -XPOST -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d @quickstart/tutorial/wikipedia-kafka-supervisor.json http://localhost:8090/druid/indexer/v1/supervisor
```

If the supervisor is successfully created, you will get the ID of the supervisor as a response; for example:

```
 {"id":"wikipedia-kafka"}
```

Comment: Ok I did it but get the error
    Problem accessing /druid/v2/supervisor

Comment: @HibaRehman Do you have the `wikipedia-kafka-supervisor.json` on your machine?

Comment: yes but i am not able to access /druid/v2/supervisor at localhost

Comment: Can you provide more details with regards to this issue? Do you get any error or something?